# using props in makeStyle throwing error Property 'height' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the react component as below with material styles and Typescript

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  media: {
    height: props => props.height,
    ['@media (max-width:780px)']: { // eslint-disable-line no-useless-computed-key
      height: **props => props.minHeight**
    }
  },
});

interface ImageObject{
  image: string;
  title: string;
}

interface ImageCarouselProps {
  height: number;
  minHeight: number;
  pictures: ImageObject[];
}

export const ImageCarousel = (props: ImageCarouselProps) => {
  const classes = useStyles(props);
};
```

When I compile this I am getting the error **Property 'height' does not exist on type '{}'**. and **Property 'minHeight' does not exist on type '{}'** for accessing the height propery inside the makeStyles.

how can I fix this error ?

Comment: can do console.log(...) check whether props has the height or not

Comment: @tareqaziz - console.log() is showing the properties height and minHeight.

Comment: What about changing to: 
const useStyles = makeStyles((props) => ({ ... same code here... }))
I use it in this manner and works fine, when I need to import some theme and use it instead of what you use as 'props' here.

Comment: @kbo - Yes. I tried that way as well, still getting the same error. Tried as mentioned in https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#adapting-based-on-props. still got the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Needed a little modification and it works fine in my test. Basically add type to props:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

interface ImageObject{
  image: string;
  title: string;
}

interface ImageCarouselProps {
  height: number;
  minHeight: number;
  // pictures: ImageObject[];
}

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  media: {
    height: (props: ImageCarouselProps) => props.height,
    ['@media (max-width:780px)']: { // eslint-disable-line no-useless-computed-key
      height: (props: ImageCarouselProps) => props.minHeight,
    }
  },
});

export default (props: ImageCarouselProps) => {
  const classes = useStyles(props);
  return <div className={classes.media}>test this div</div>
};
```

You probably won't have issues with the rest of the implementation - make sure to pass all the props when using the component and add the style class. Cheers!

P.S. I've commented the pictures prop in the interface, for the test to work.

Answer (score 0):

For people with style separated into another file, this worked best for me:

```
const classes: Record<string, string> = useStyles({ valueVariable: value });
```

which could then be used in the .style.ts file:

```
classname:{
  color: (prop: { valueVariable: number }) => prop.valueVariable,
},
```